# Enum Validation using Fluent API

Tags: c#, ef-fluent-api

I need to use `FluentAPI` to validate that the property contains a value of the `CourseEnum` shown below. How can I write this validation in `FluentAPI`. So basically, the `Course` property should contain either `Math` or `Science`. I have given my workings below:

```
public enum CourseEnum
{
    Math= 1, 
    Science  
}
```

Fluent

```
builder.Property(c => c.Course)
     .IsRequired(true);
```

Comment: This can be option for u - .HasColumnType("INT CHECK (PropertyName IN (1, 2, ...))")

Comment: @spzvtbg instead of hard coding the options 1 and 2. Can it be read from the ENUM it self ?

Comment: sure: `var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<int>();`  `.HasColumnType($"INT CHECK (PropertyName IN ({string.Join(", ", values)}))");`